# Dynamic Query in Java date interval

Tags: java, liferay-6

I use Liferay 6.2, 
I try to select elements with a `DynamicQuery`.

I have a model `Event` that contains `startDate` and `endDate` columns.

```
ClassLoader cl = Event.class.getClassLoader();
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Event.class, cl);
```

I want to make a query to select rows of the table between `startDate` and `endDate`.

How i can do that?

Comment: I found this https://gist.github.com/bmvakili/d9afddca884e86d78a13 example.

Comment: It refers to only one column 'createDate'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that the function

- `Property.lt(Object)` means *lower than*,
- `Property.le(Object)` means *lower or equals*,
- `Property.gt(Object)` means *greater than* and,
- `Property.ge(Object)` means *greater or equals*?

You can use this knowledge as follows:

```
Date startDate = ...;
Date endDate = ...;
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Event.class, Event.class.getClassLoader());
Property startDateProperty = PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("startDate");
Property endDateProperty = PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("endDate");
dynamicQuery.add(startDateProperty.ge(startDate));
dynamicQuery.add(endDateProperty.le(endDate));
```

This will find all events, that are *completely* between a given `startDate` and `endDate`. If you want to find all events that somehow *overlap* a given date range, you will need this:

```
dynamicQuery.add(startDateProperty.lt(endDate));
dynamicQuery.add(endDateProperty.gt(startDate));
```